# How to get new font to be used in html?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-family

[image]

This is the font type have to use while designing in html but no font family type matching the font.
Which font types is this and if not such font available on system then from where and how to get that
to match above font-family?

Comment: ask to your designer font family and search to net and used to your html as custom font

Comment: Try https://www.google.com/fonts

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because font identification questions are not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

The questions is more for google. But You can use font detection websites. I use [this](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) when in need.

Answer (score -1):

You have got access to the designer of this? He/she could tell you. Otherwise, please try this http://www.fontspring.com/matcherator, it may help you.

Thanks